# Weird Access Query Problem - Running Saved Access Query Can't Find Fields. Is this a Buffer problem?

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Version 1 of the problem:**
I create a simple (or complex) SQL query that works and save it, and then come back to it another day and try to run it.  I get a message that it cannot find a field that is clearly in the table.  If I copy the exact same query into a blank SQL window it works fine.

**Version 2 of the problem:**
Another version of this type of problem is when I write a query, run it a bunch of times, and then modify it in the same window, it sometimes (=quite often but not always) can't find a field that is clearly in the table.  Again, copying the same query into a new window works just fine.

An example:
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE code1='xxx' and code2= 'yyy' 
ORDER BY sortfield

I get the window saying 'Enter Parameter value for field Query1.sortfield' .
 sortfield is in the table and copying this query to a new window works fine.
And to be clear, the query worked fine when first written.

Seems like Access is not properly clearing the buffer somehow.

I have Access 2010 and this happens very frequently, like maybe but not quite always, and seems to be getting worse.  I have always had version 2 of the problem to some extent but version 1 is relatively new.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: When you get the *"Enter Parameter value for field Query1.sortfield"* message, what is the name of the query you're attempting to run?  Is it *"Query1"* or something else?

Comment: In version 1, I save it to some unique name that is applicable to the purpose. I don't use something generic like query1.  In version 2, I am not saving queries, just modifying and re-running.  Thanks!

Comment: Examine the query's property sheet, especially the Order By and Filter properties if present.  Does one of the properties reference *Query1.sortfield*?

Comment: I may not have properly answered your first question.  The query is saved as s1 and the 'Enter parameter value' window literally says 'Query1.sortfield'

Comment: On your question about properties, I think that is it, but why does this get stored? The order by property has Query1.sortfield plus several other fields. Is this possibly because while working with the data before I saved the query, I may have sorted by different fields and then saved it?  And it kept the non-saved internal name 'Query1' rather than the saved query name?

Comment: My guess is this: When you created the query, Access used *"Query1"* as its name.  While the query was in Datasheet View, you right-clicked the *"sortfield"* column header and chose a *Sort* option.  That added an *"OrderBy"* property to the query which included the current query name, *"Query1"*.  Later you saved the query with a different name, *"s1"*, but the property still included the former name.